# Amazon-S3 urls to shipped hard-drive service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup, hard-drive, aws-snowball

Is there a service that will take a list of Amazon S3 urls from the customer, download and copy the files into one/many hard-drives, then ship the hard-drives to the customer for a fee?

I am thinking about something like Amazon Snowball, but that sends hard-drives to the customer, and these can simply be shelved when they arrive at the customer's destination.

EDIT: It looks like Amazon Snowball and Amazon Import/Export Disks implement some of the features, but the client (me) still has to do some of the work. So I guess I am after a company that does these middle man extra steps and just ships the final disks to the client where they are shelved.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas?  [Read the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSImportExport/latest/DG/whatisdisk.html).  This is how AWS Import/Export Disk works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve that using AWS Snowball but you will not get the data in hard drive but you will get it in a Snowball appliance owned by AWS.

Check this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSImportExport/latest/ug/getting-started.html?console_help=true

Comment: I see. So a step further which is what I am thinking would be to put it in inexpensive hard-drives that once sent, the customer can keep.

Comment: Yes you will have to put that in a hard drive